# Loading from main.jsbundle on device: "Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've been building a react-native app and up till now it's been working fine with both remote JS bundle and also local bundle, having run `react-native bundle`. However as of today my local bundle will not load on my device whatever I try. I keep getting the following stack trace upon launching of the app:

```
2018-01-03 16:54:28.758526+0000 App[5750:1165819] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E0103 16:54:29.372881 1847881728 JSCHelpers.cpp:137] Got JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364)
E0103 16:54:29.373000 1847881728 JSCHelpers.cpp:143] Got JS Stack: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364:6244
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364:156
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364:197
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:362:1781
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:361:103
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:360:136
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:298:317
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:12:38
t@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:620
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:2:154
global code@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:722:9
E0103 16:54:29.376503 1847881728 JSCHelpers.cpp:137] Got JS Exception: Exception calling object as function: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication) (<unknown file>:14)
E0103 16:54:29.376549 1847881728 JSCHelpers.cpp:143] Got JS Stack: exports@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:14:306
value@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:18:2937
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:18:812
value@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:18:2507
value@/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:18:784
value@[native code]
2018-01-03 16:54:29.377 [fatal][tid:main] Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364)
2018-01-03 16:54:29.378191+0000 App[5750:1165546] Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364)
2018-01-03 16:54:29.378319+0000 App[5750:1165546] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout (/var/containers/Bundle/Application/19F39B2A-43F0-4FB1-BD1D-34254608E4BB/App.app/main.jsbundle:364)', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: setTimeout (/var/containers/Bu...'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18295e364 0x181ba4528 0x18295e2ac 0x1029f4344 0x1029dfe44 0x104a452cc 0x104a4528c 0x104a49ea0 0x182906544 0x182904120 0x182823e58 0x1846cef84 0x18bea2844 0x102993684 0x18234056c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I've tried re-installing all node_modules and all pods, cleaning the project and re-bundling the JS with no luck. Strangely the app still works when loading the bundle remotely.

Comment: Have you updated your NodeJS version?

Comment: Might be problem with your network(wi-fi). I also faced same kind of problem when I connect to some networks with different configurations(enabling firewalls etc). Once check whether bundling is being done in simulator.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I am running into the same setTimeout exception now. Thanks!

Comment: @Poke Same problem... Have you fixed it? It seems like google signin causes the problem...

Comment: @crispychicken I ran this `yarn upgrade react-native@0.56.0` (replace w/ version you are using)